# AngularJS Filter being called related to number of scopes on the page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a page that has a number of directives.  There are a number of directives in the header/navigation each with there own scope.  There is also a ng-repeat of 25 items and each one of those creates a directive each with its own scope.

One of the directives includes a form that includes a custom filter to display form errors, it looks like this:

```
<span>{{ createProjectForm.name.$error | nagParseErrors }}</span>
```

Now the concern I have right now is that nagParseErrors is being executed about 33 times when anything in any scope changes even though this data createProjectForm.name is binded to (with ng-model) is only contained in the controller scope and the directive's scope containing the form (which is just being passed to the directive from the controller scope).  I know it is related to the number of scopes (or directives) on the page because if I limit the ng-repeat from 25 items to 1, the filter is only called 9 times.  This also happend for built-in filters (like json, and it even runs more times).

Is there something I might be doing wrong here or is this in fact how it should work in AngularJS?

BTW, I realize now that displaying the errors might be better off as a directive than a filter I am planning on going the directive route however I would like to clear up my understanding of filters here since I will probably run into this at some point down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been addressed numerous times. All AngularJS expressions will be constantly re-evaluated throughout the lifecycle of the app. This is how two-way databinding in AngularJS works.

So, there's nothing wrong with your code. It's just that you need to make sure your filter is idempotent (returns the same output given the same input).

For more info take a look at [Why Scope.$apply() calls $rootScope.$digest() rather than this.$digest()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333410/why-scope-apply-calls-rootscope-digest-rather-than-this-digest/12359790#12359790) and [scope docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).