# Running $apply on $rootScope vs any other scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

The `$apply` function can run on any scope, including `$rootScope`.

Are there cases when it makes a difference if I run it on my local scope or if I run it on my `$rootScope`?

I'm asking because I'd like to create a helper function that wraps a given function in an `$apply`.  To do that I'd always need to pass in a scope, which is A) annoying and B) not easy because I don't necessarily have a local scope.

I'd like to always have my helper function call `$apply` on the `$rootScope`, but not if there's some risk in doing that.

Comment: At first thought this sounded bad but searching a bit it looks like calling $apply on any scope is going to cause $rootScope.$digest to run anyhow so I don't believe you would suffer any performance loss, but it'd be worth testing some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333410/why-scope-apply-calls-rootscope-digest-rather-than-this-digest

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Running `$apply` on any scope always results in a `$rootscope.$digest`. The only case where it might make a difference is when you provide an expression as an argument to `$apply`. The expression will be evaluated in the current scope (vs. $rootScope), but afterwards `$rootscope.$digest` is *always* called.

The source code is quite clear: [rootScope.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.16/src/ng/rootScope.js#L886-L901)

Bottom line:
If you call `$apply` with no arguments, it makes no difference.

Comment: It makes a difference if the code before the apply with no parameter  throws an exception. That exception is not caught by angular's error handling.

Comment: Are you saying there is a difference between `thisThrowsAnError();$scope.$apply()` and `thisThrowsAnError();$rootScope.$apply()` ?

Comment: I was reffering to $anyScope.$apply(function () {/*throws error*/}) vs /*thorws error*/;$anyScope.$apply(). The latter one is does not go through error handler of angular

Comment: Best  practice: use `$timeout` instead of `$rootScope.$apply()` in order to avoid hard-to-debug error "digest already in progress"

Answer (score 15):

Another reason for running `$apply` on the `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` typically comes for me when I need to call `$apply` in a service which will be used by different controllers and therefore different scopes.
In this cases I prefer to inject the `$rootScope` to the service and call $apply on it without worrying on which scopes the service will be used in the future.

Comment: Great point.. in fact passing scope to a service should really be a documented anti-pattern

Answer (score 11):

Running $digest/$apply on any given scope will visit all other scopes using depth-first traversal:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3967f5f7d6c8aa7b41a5352b12f457e2fbaa251a/src/ng/rootScope.js#L550-L558

That means that the only difference is that the $digest will start at whatever $scope it was called on

Comment: $digest will always be called on the $rootScope. I explain it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* What happens with $apply */ 
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageController', function($scope) {
    
      $scope.getMessage = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            //wrapped this within $apply
            $scope.message = 'Fetched after 3 seconds'; 
            console.log('message:' + $scope.message);
          });
        }, 2000);
      }
      
      $scope.getMessage();
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MessageController">
        Delayed Message: {{message}}
      </div>  
    </body>
```