# Why does angularjs $scope.$digest() updates the parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm so confused using `$scope.$digest()` method. As far as I know when we call `$scope.$digest()` its won't update the parent scope value, so

> its processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its
>   children

, but when I call `$scope.$digest()` its also update the parent scope, in this case the `$rootScope`.

In the following example, I have a demonstration. In the `$rootScope` I have a variable named `value_on_root`, so every time I call `onchange` event on the  input I call an angular function and inside it I change the value of the variable `file_src` which is on the `$scope` and also I change the value for the variable `value_on_root` which is on the `$rootScope`, so when I call `$scope.$digest` its update call the watchers on `$rootScope` too.

Check the example here

[Click to see example in CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGaQWE)

Answer (score 3):

[Per This Article](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/):

"The $digest cycle starts as a result of a call to $scope.$digest(). Assume that you change a scope model in a handler function through the ng-click directive. In that case AngularJS automatically triggers a $digest cycle by calling $digest(). When the $digest cycle starts, it fires each of the watchers. These watchers check if the current value of the scope model is different from last calculated value. If yes, then the corresponding listener function executes. As a result if you have any expressions in the view they will be updated. In addition to ng-click, there are several other built-in directives/services that let you change models (e.g. ng-model, $timeout, etc) and automatically trigger a $digest cycle.

So far, so good! But, there is a small gotcha. In the above cases, **Angular doesn’t directly call $digest(). Instead, it calls $scope.$apply(), which in turn calls $rootScope.$digest(). As a result of this, a digest cycle starts at the $rootScope, and subsequently visits all the child scopes calling the watchers along the way.**"

The rootscope variable is then updated and you see the change in your codepen.

Comment: Hi @Kreepn, thanks for you answer but you're not answer my question at all, in this answer you're telling me about how the digest cycle works on angularjs and already I know that. When you call $scope.$digest() its processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children, so if you saw my example, there is a variable that lives in the $rootScope and even though I call $scope.$digest() this variable is updated.

Comment: @evolquez Pretty sure it's the exact answer to your question. Due to the chaining nature of the calls, the single call to $digest triggers the rootscope to check its own properties. You make a change via `$rootScope.value_on_root = "Value updated";` and it updates it accordingly in you codepen.

Comment: @evolquez Exact same explanation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333410/why-scope-apply-calls-rootscope-digest-rather-than-this-digest

Answer (score 0):

The confusion stems from your interpretation of `$scope.$digest` below:

> As far as I know when we call $scope.$digest() its won't update the parent scope value

The parent scope's value *will* always update if you add or modify a property to that scope object. This is true of any JS object (unless that object is frozen or otherwise unable to receive updates/new properties, but that point is not important in this case).

Now, whether that scope object's new or modified property is reflected in the DOM is another story.

In your example [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGaQWE), you are updating the root scope by giving it a new value in your controller as such:

```
$rootScope.value_on_root = "Value updated";
```

The reason why this update is reflected in the DOM is due to two things:

1. You have implicitly registered a watcher for `value_on_root` in your controller's scope object in your HTML below:

   ```
   <div><strong>{{value_on_root}}</strong></div>
   ```
2. Your controller's scope is using prototypical inheritance, so the property `value_on_root` can be accessed through your controller's scope. [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) is a great article explaining scope inheritance in AngularJS. From the  article:

   > If we try to access a property defined on the parentScope from the child scope, JavaScript will first look in the child scope, not find the property, then look in the inherited scope, and find the property. (If it didn't find the property in the parentScope, it would continue up the prototype chain... all the way up to the root scope).

In your example, because you have a `value_on_root` watcher in your current scope (due to point #1 above) and because `value_on_root` is accessible through your current scope (due to point #2 above), `$digest` is doing exactly what it is supposed to:

> it processes all of the watchers of the current scope and its children

If we had a `value_on_root` watcher outside of the current scope, or if your controller's scope had an [isolate scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive), updates to properties on `$rootScope` would not be reflected in the DOM.

I slightly modified your codepen [in this example](https://codepen.io/chrissantos1995/pen/vWmdJL) to prove my point. I implicitly placed a `value_on_root` watcher outside of the controller's scope by adding `{{value_on_root}}` to the surrounding HTML. Notice that in this example, the outer `value_on_root` is not updated when you upload an image.

If you change `$digest` to `$apply` in [my example](https://codepen.io/chrissantos1995/pen/vWmdJL), then the outer `value_on_root` does get updated.